# Best way to select specific characters from a variable output?

Tags: powershell

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-702)
$path = "X:\"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }

$new = $files | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14" -and $_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30" }

$sorted = $new | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "#"}
```

So here the output looks like this

[image]

What would be the smartest way to take the Name example "S002567.5050b3d7.mxf" and make the output "S002567"? So to scrape away everything from the "."

Best reguards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with PowerShell, there are two things to remember.

1. PowerShell is object-oriented.
2. PowerShell uses pipelines.

To the extent you can stick to these rules, you will have more options and your work will be easier.

You can add information to the objects created by `Get-ChildItem` using [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1).

Use regular expressions to grab text.

### You can take the first seven characters of the name.

```
$this.Name -match "^.{7}"
```

- `^` is the beginning of a *string*: `$this.Name` in this case. $this.Name is equivalent to $_.Name and is required for a [ScriptProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1#notes).
- `.` is any character.
- `{7}` grabs seven total characters.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-702)
$path = "X:\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | 
  Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14") -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30") -and 
                 ($_.Name -notmatch "#")
               } | 
  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "TruncatedName" -Value { $this.Name -match "^.{7}" | Out-Null; $matches[0] } -PassThru | 
  Where-Object TruncatedName | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, TruncatedName
```

### You can match a particular pattern.

```
$this.Name -match "^S\d{6}"
```

- `^` is the beginning of a string.
- `S` is a literal capital 's'.
- `\d` is a number.
- `{6}` is six numbers.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-702)
$path = "X:\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | 
  Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14") -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30") -and 
                 ($_.Name -notmatch "#")
               } | 
  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "TruncatedName" -Value { $this.Name -match "^S\d{6}" | Out-Null; $matches[0] } -PassThru | 
  Where-Object TruncatedName | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, TruncatedName
```

---

`Where-Object TruncatedName` limits the output to just names that were matched with the regular expression. Otherwise all files will be passed down the pipeline whether they received truncated names or not.

It is possible to use a static date rather than an offset.

```
$limit = Get-Date "January 1, 2019"
```

Use `Get-ChildItem -File` instead of `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }`

Each cmdlet in a pipeline passes a value as soon as it is done processing. By eliminating temporary variables, we process data more efficiently.

Lines of code that end with a pipe will preserve the pipeline.

Spaces are ignored. And anytime the parser sees missing information (like with `-and` at the end of a line or unclosed curly braces `{ }`), it will continue processing on the next line.

Group clauses with parentheses `( )`.

```
# started with
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }
$new = $files | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14" -and $_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30" }
$sorted = $new | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "#"}

# using a single, readable pipeline
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | 
  Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14") -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30") -and 
                 ($_.Name -notmatch "#")
               }
```

---

If you want strings instead of `FileInfo` objects, emit the strings explicitly with `| ForEach-Object TruncatedName`.

```
$limit = Get-Date "January 1, 2019" 
$path = "X:\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | 
  Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt "18:14") -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt "18:30") -and 
                 ($_.Name -notmatch "#")
               } | 
  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "TruncatedName" -Value { $this.Name -match "^.{7}" | Out-Null; $matches[0] } -PassThru | 
  Where-Object TruncatedName | 
  ForEach-Object TruncatedName
```

---

You might move the other variables out of the pipeline.

```
$limit = Get-Date "January 1, 2019" 
$path = "X:\"
$startTime = "18:14"
$endTime = "18:30"
$dontMatch = "#"
$doMatch = "^.{7}"
$propertyName = "TruncatedName"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | 
  Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -gt $startTime) -and 
                 ($_.LastWriteTime.TimeOfDay -lt $endTime) -and 
                 ($_.Name -notmatch $dontMatch)
               } | 
  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name $propertyName -Value { $this.Name -match $doMatch | Out-Null; $matches[0] } -PassThru | 
  Where-Object $propertyName | 
  ForEach-Object $propertyName
```

---

References

- [about_Comparison_Operators - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
- [Regular-Expressions.info - Regex Tutorial, Examples and Reference - Regexp Patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10))

Answer (score 1):

I think the "smartest" way would be opinion based, but one easy way would be to simply split on the period and grab the first element.

```
$Sorted | Foreach-Object {($_.Basename -split '\.')[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the file objects to `ForEach-Object` and then manipulate the `Name` property of each:

```
$sorted |ForEach-Object { $_.Name -replace '\..*$' }
```

The regex pattern used with the `-replace` operator will find and remove the first `.` and everything after it:

```
\.      # literal dot
  .*    # any number of any character
    $   # end of string
```